# Why KML format is not visible?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, kml

I have a KML file viewer made in OpenLayers using the following code:

```
var vector = new OpenLayers.layer.Vector({
        source: new OpenLayers.source.Vector({
          url: window.Laravel.baseUrl + "/" + item.items,
          format: new OpenLayers.format.KML({})         

        })
      });

      this.mapshape.addLayer(vector);
      var vectorSource = vector.getSource();

      vectorSource.on("change", e => {
        if (vectorSource.getState() === "ready") {

          this.zoomAbove(vectorSource.getExtent());
        }
      });
```

the zoomAbove method has:

```
zoomAbove: function(extent) {
  this.mapshape.getView().fit(extent, this.mapshape.getSize());
},
```

I can view some files without problems as shown in the following image
[image]

the problem is with certain files showing only a blank map
[image]

I have opened the files in QGIS and they all have the same EPSG: 4326, what could be the problem ?

I update my question and add EXAMPLE KML files.

1.-This KML file is not visible
[enter link description here](https://res.cloudinary.com/djj897uo4/raw/upload/v1584640314/1584640247kml_of9so4.kml)

2.-This KML file is visible
[enter link description here](https://res.cloudinary.com/djj897uo4/raw/upload/v1584640390/1584639482kml_ercz5f.kml)

Comment: Can you include examples of working and nonworking KML? Without files it would all be just guessing.

Comment: update my question and added two examples @TomazicM

Comment: Unfortunately both links to .kml files point to the same file.

Comment: ready is updated @TomazicM

Comment: I managed to view both files in online KML viewer http://kmlviewer.nsspot.net/, but when I tried to convert nonworking one with GPSBabel, I got the following error: `XML Reader:Read error: Namespace prefix 'xsi' not declared (D:/Downloads/1584640247kml_of9so4.kml, line 3, col 221)`. Obviously there is some schema problem that some viewers overlook and some trip on it. I'm not KML expert so I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Thanks @TomazicM, I removed the 'xsi' property and reloaded my file, now I can see it on the map